# List<Trail> cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Hi I have the following code which populates a listview with data that i receive using the Retrofit http client.

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item_details);


    if (mlabAPi.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please obtain your API KEY from!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }


    ApiInterface apiService =
            MlabApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Trail>> call = apiService.byTrailID(countyString,mlabAPi);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Trail>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Trail>> call, Response<List<Trail>> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            List<Trail> trails = response.body();
            listView.setAdapter(new WalkDetailsAdapter(trails,R.layout.list_item_details, )); **<-HERE**
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Trail>> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());

        }
    });
```

Which is giving me the errorError:(127, 60) error: incompatible types: List cannot be converted to Context.

I think the error is the third parameter of the listView.setAdapter, would anyone know what is the third parameter i must add is,
 (I tried getApplicatinonContext, as thats what i used when populating the recyclerview.)  What would be the listview equivalent?

Thank You.

Walkdetailsadapter

```
   public class WalkDetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Trail> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Trail> values;

    public WalkDetailsAdapter ( Context context, List<Trail> values){
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_details, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_details, parent, false);

        }


        TextView textViewName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView textViewCounty = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.county);
        TextView textViewFormat = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.format);
        TextView textViewTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.time);
        TextView textViewLength = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.length);
        //TextView textViewGrade = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.grade);
        TextView textViewDifficultly = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.diffuctlty);
        TextView textViewQuality= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quality);
        TextView textViewStart = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.start);
        TextView textViewFinish = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.finish);

        Trail item = values.get(position);
        String trail = item.getTrailName();
        textViewName.setText(trail);

        String county = item.getCounty();
        textViewCounty.setText(county);

        String format = item.getFormat();
        textViewFormat.setText(format);

        String time = item.getTime();
        textViewTime.setText(time);

        String length = item.getDistance();
        textViewLength.setText(length);

        String diff = item.getGrade();
        textViewDifficultly.setText(diff);

        String quality = item.getQuality();
        textViewQuality.setText(quality);

        String start = item.getStartTown();
        textViewStart.setText(start);

        String finish = item.getFinishTown();
        textViewFinish.setText(finish);

        return row;



    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the WalkDetailsAdapter?

Comment: The constructor for `WalkDetailsAdapter` almost certainly takes a `Context` as the first argument. You have your list as the first argument; hence the error message.

Comment: Hi i added the Walk Adapter code there.

Comment: the first param to WalkDetailsAdapter is a Context. Try passing in MainActivity.this otherwise this will refer to Callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch this

`listView.setAdapter(new WalkDetailsAdapter(trails,R.layout.list_item_details, ));`

to this

`listView.setAdapter(new WalkDetailsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),trails));`

The problem was that in your WalkDetailsAdapter class, the constructor arguments are a `Context` and a `List<Trail>` and you were providing it with the list and then a layout resource. So just switch the arguments so that the first is a context by using `getApplicationContext()` or `getContext()` or `this` depending on what the class is, and the second to an instance of `List<Trail>` and then it should work.